# Access SoapClient and file_get_contents from local LAMP

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, soap, virtualhost

I'm working under ubuntu 12.04.
I have a classic localhost set up . apache + mysql + php

file_get_contents fail on external url but works well with local file or 'localhost'

```
file_get_contents('http://google.com');
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://google.com): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!
```

soapClient fail on external url but works well with local file or 'localhost'

```
$wsdl = "http://test.webservices.delijn.be/wsrise/services/travel/WEB-INF/wsdl/RiseWebservices.wsdl";
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl,
array(
        'trace'                 => true,
        'exceptions'            => true,
        'soap_version'          => SOAP_1_1,
        'connection_timeout'    => 600,
        'compression' => SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT ,
        'encoding'=> 'UTF-8', //ISO-8859-1',
        //'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_BOTH,
        //'host'     => "localhost",
        //'proxy_host'     => "localhost",
        //'proxy_port'     => 8080,
    ));

SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 
'http://test.webservices.delijn.be/wsrise/services/travel/WEB-INF/wsdl/RiseWebservices.wsdl' : failed to load external entity "http://test.webservices.delijn.be/wsrise/services/travel/WEB-INF/wsdl/RiseWebservices.wsdl"
```

allow_url_fopen and allow_include_url are on in phpinfo() (set in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini)
firewall is disabled
apparmor is disabled

suhosin patch is installed and i set suhosin.simulation to true in the php.ini

the code is working well on my production and staging servers

I 'm out of ideas and don't find intresting log or command that can inspect the problem :'(

Thanks for your help !

Comment: @Quasdunk Trailing commas in arrays won't throw a syntax error, and are sometimes required by some coding standards.

Comment: have you tried from the shell to access those sites? just do `curl http://test.webservices.delijn.be/wsrise/services/travel/WEB-INF/wsdl/RiseWebservices.wsdl`

Comment: @MikeB What the.... My whole life was a lie :-D Thanks for the comment, I wasn't really aware of that! (It does throw an exception if there is nothing but a comma, though.)

Comment: curl and GET in shell works well .

Answer (score 1):

Ok ! I found a way to make it work.

install de suhosin-php package in order to be able to use the Module suhosin.
set the suhosin.simulation directive to on in /etc/php5/con.d/suhosin.conf
sudo service apache2 restart

Soap calls are still extremely slow, but are working now

Thanks for your help !